# find files and exclude some files and a directory

Tags: bash, shell, grep, find

I want to find in a directory all files with extension `.hs` but exclude all files in a sub-directory `sub` and some other files with names containing `test`. 
I read and experimented with the use of `find` and `prune` but did not understand the complex logic and none of my attempts worked.

The naive

```
find . -name "*.hs" -not -name '*sub*' -not -name "*test*"
```

nor

```
find . -name "*.hs" -not -path '/sub' -not -name "*test*"
```

does work. I assume there should be a simple solution to this (relatively) simple issue.

A solution that seems to work is

```
find . -name "*.hs"   -not -name "*test*"   | grep -v  "sub"
```

which is simpler than using `prune`, but can certainly be improved?

Comment: Why do you not want to use `-prune` and how is it more complex than what you have tried?

Comment: could you show me the exmple case with prune - I did not succeed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first attempt excludes all files whose name includes `sub`.

Your second attempt excludes all files whose path is exactly `/sub`.

Combine the two to match all files whose path includes `sub`:

```
-not -path "*sub*"
```

However, `-prune` is the better solution because it skips the directory rather than fruitlessly matching every single entry in it.

Comment: Thank yuo - it works perfectly (I assume that I had some other strange effects (typo?) in my attempts).